# FutureWarning in scikit-learn Logistic Regression solver

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have been using a course on Udemy for learning Machine-Learning. I have found a lot of deprecated code and now I have this issue:

The code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The warning:

```
C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
```

How can I get rid of this deprecation warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scikit-learn v0.20, which you probably use, the default value for the `solver` used in `LogisticRegression` was `liblinear`; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn-linear-model-logisticregression):

> **solver : *str, {‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’}, default: ‘liblinear’***.

This changed in [v0.22](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) (current latest) to `lbfgs`.

So, in order to avoid surprizes from this change, scikit-learn warns you for this change in the default that *will* come in future versions, in order to keep your code future-proof.

To get rid of it, just define explicitly a solver in your `LogisticRegression` definition, i.e.

```
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver='lbfgs') # default in v0.22
```

or

```
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver='liblinear') # default until v0.21
```

The first documentation link provided above shows all the available options, along with some short comment/advice on each one.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the warning message is telling you. All you need to do is to explicitly specify which solver to use:

```py
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver='lbfgs')
```

(or any other solver you want to use)

For available options, see [the sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver="liblinear")
```

And checkout solver parameter in the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html